# Making the parsing of a String to an Int32 robust (valid, positive, not 0 validation)

Tags: c#, validation

I've a static method which parses a String (from the App.config) to a Int32. I need to have a valid (since the parsing would fail of course^^), positive and not zero integer. I've done it like this:

```
    public static int uiScale ()
    {

        int retint = 0;

        try
        {

            retint = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("UiScale"));

        }
        catch (FormatException) {}
        catch (OverflowException){}

        return retint != 0 ? Math.Abs(retint) : 1;

    }
```

This feels (don't ask me why) a little bit smelly I've to admit. Is this the best way to achieve this?

Comment: use `int.TryParse`

Comment: @t3chb0t Thanks! _return int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("UiScale"), out retint) && retint != 0 ? Math.Abs(retint) : 1_ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: parsing

The shortest you can do is

```
int uiScale;
return 
    int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("UiScale")‌​, out uiScale) 
    && uiScale!= 0 ? Math.Abs(uiScale) : 1 ;
```

---

Second: style

**uiScale**

This method should be called either `GetUiScale` or be a property if named `UiScale` because in C# we use *PascalCase* for public members and methods *usually* contain a verb (where it makes sense).

**retint**

Don't just call it like this. It's better to use the *real* name that better describes the purpose of the variable so `uiScale` would be fine.